# \ escape character passed as json in PutAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, json.net, put, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a PUT request to update some data.  In Fiddler in the Inspectors > Text View the data is shown as following :

```
"{\"site\":[{\"technologyId\":1,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":2,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":3,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":4,\"isActive\":1}]}"
```

If I open the jsonData in TextViewer while debugging it shows the following:

```
{"site":[{"technologyId":1,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":2,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":3,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":4,"isActive":1}]}
```

I thought this is what is passed to the server when I passed jsonData in PutAsJsonAsync.

In fiddler the response comes back as 500 Internal Server Error and if I click on TextView it shows `{"error":"Error: invalid json"}`.  To my understanding the `\` is escape character for `"` in C# and should not be passed.  I am not sure how to resolve this

```
static void Main()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Uri siteTechUpdateUrl = new Uri("http://xyz/api/1234");
        // HTTP PUT
        // Update site# 16839 Technologies

        var collection = new List<SiteTechnology>();
        collection.Add(new SiteTechnology() { technologyId = 1, isActive = 1 });
        collection.Add(new SiteTechnology() { technologyId = 2, isActive = 1 });
        collection.Add(new SiteTechnology() { technologyId = 3, isActive = 1 });
        collection.Add(new SiteTechnology() { technologyId = 4, isActive = 1 });
        dynamic siteTechs= new
        {
            site = collection
        };
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(siteTechs);  
        // jsonData value "{\"site\":[{\"technologyId\":1,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":2,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":3,\"isActive\":1},{\"technologyId\":4,\"isActive\":1}]}"               
        HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(siteTechUpdateUrl, jsonData);

        if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class SiteTechnology
{
    public int technologyId;
    public int isActive;
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the server you are `PUT`ing to?

Comment: No I do not have access to the code on the server. I tested the PUT using curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" –d @data.json http://xyz/api/1234 and it succeeded.  The data.json file has the following {"site":[{"technologyId":1,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":2,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":3,"isActive":1},{"technologyId":4,"isActive":1}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're serializing it to a string, and then sending the string as JSON.

Instead of:

```
client.PutAsJsonAsync(siteTechUpdateUrl, jsonData);
```

try:

```
client.PutAsJsonAsync(siteTechUpdateUrl, siteTechs);
```